# why does quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/<realm>/upload?minorversion=45 returns: "Maximum line length limit exceeded"

Tags: quickbooks, multipart, intuit-partner-platform

we are sending the following multipart request:

```
--BYhJbicYjpSMGwjH
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_content_01"; filename="8.thumbnail.jpg"
<base_64_file>
--BYhJbicYjpSMGwjH--
```

to
`quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/<realm>/upload?minorversion=45`
but we are getting back:

```
{
    'Fault': {
        'Error': [{
            'Message': 'An application error has occurred while processing your request', 
            'Detail': 'System Failure Error: Maximum line length limit exceeded', 'code': '10000'
        }], 
       'type': 'SystemFault'
    }, 
    'time': '2020-03-11T04:13:44.324-07:00'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

adding a `new line` before the `<base_64_file>` solved the issue.